# Web Clipper Portlet not displaying the clipped content in IBM WPS 7.0

Tags: clipping, websphere-portal

I am trying to clip an external application using IBM Web Clipper portlet. I am totally unaware of the specifications of the external application. All I need to do is to mention the URL in the Web Clipper Portlet page. But after doing so, the content is not getting displayed and inturn i am getting the following error message:

```
WCSVC0010W: The content for "http://www.google.com" could not be retrieved! Please consult the WebSphere Portal Server log files.

NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is to look at the logs as the error message indicates. Hopefully the logs are more verbose as to why the content could not be retrieved.

Second idea is to check if your server can access the target URL. A firewall or something similar could be preventing your server from reaching outside URLs (like www.google.com). Log onto the server and try to ping your target URL.